# what's using all my memory?

Tags: kernel, memory, top

[image]

```
OS: Void Linux x86_64
Kernel: 4.13.0+
Shell: zsh 5.4.2
Terminal: xterm
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1800X (16) @ 3.600GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080
GPU: AMD Radeon RX Vega 64
```

on boot it starts with about 170MB and then just gradually grows indefinitely. computer eventually hangs, though that may be unrelated. i dont believe this is kernel cache, i tried clearing it with `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` but still the same memory usage.

Comment: Provide a textual representation of the information from which you derive that you are missing some memory, not an image.

Comment: To echo Patrick's comment, see https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Answer (score 1):

You could use [smem](https://www.selenic.com/smem/) which could point you to the information you are looking for. There is a good write up of it here, https://linuxaria.com/pills/linux-terminal-check-who-uses-all-your-memory-with-smem